# Different behaviour in GKE between etcd and PV storage for same key action

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, etcd, kubernetes-pvc, google-cloud-kms

GKE natively works with customer supplied key (using KMS), including actions like key rotation, key disabling/enabling for etcd / content in control plane.

While customer supplied key (using KMS) also works for encryption of dynamic PV mounts (using storage class),
it doesn't support actions like key rotation, key disabling/enabling.
For example, disabling the key has no effect on already mounted PV.

Why this difference? Are these two implementation drastically different?

Answer (score 1):

According to the  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-supplied-keys) on the Customer Supplied Encryption key.

If an object is encrypted using a customer-supplied encryption key, you can rotate the object's key by [rewriting the object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite). Rewrites are supported through the JSON API, but not the XML API. See [Rotating an encryption](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/using-customer-supplied-keys#rotating) key for examples of key rotation.

You can also refer to the stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065678/googles-key-management-system-data-unencryption-after-key-rotation?rq=1).